80's B-movie about people deathly afraid of meat
In the late 90's I rented a movie about an evil organisation whose members were deathly afraid of meat. In the movie's climax, the protagonist is at their base threatening everyone with a sausage, and in a memorable scene, one takes a large bite out of the sausage, initially to no effect but then his head explodes!
An early scene in the movie shows a detective in a car parked near a lake, and was overwhelmed by a swarm of frogs/toads.

It sounds like the movie Leonard Part 6. 
Here is the head-explodey scene. 

The movie starts with Parker being re-recruited by his former employers in the CIA to save the world from an evil vegetarian who brainwashes animals to kill people. The film ends with Leonard infiltrating the vegetarian base, fending off the vegetarians with magic meat he received from a Gypsy, freeing the captive animals and flooding the base using Alka-Seltzer. He escapes by riding an ostrich on the roof of the building, with the ostrich flying him down.



That's the one! What a horrible movie
